# How does one hard code data into a data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

below is the sample data and the manipulation. One will notice that in Month1 for each indcode that there is an NA for the empprevmonth and therefore empprevmonthchg. How would one hard code data into these columns. Yes, I know that there is a limit to the data hence the NA but what if I did want to manually input numbers after the fact? Can this be done?

```
 periodyear3 <-c(2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020)
 month3<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6)
 indcode3<-c(624410,624410,624410,624410,624410,624410,72,72,72,72,72,72)
 employment3 <-c(25,25,26,27,28,29,85,86,87,88,89,90)
 wages3 <-c(10000,10001,10002,10003,10004,10005,12510,12515,12520,12520,16528,19874)

 example <- data.frame (periodyear3,month3,indcode3,employment3,wages3)


 example<- example%>%
 group_by(indcode3)%>%
 mutate(empprevmonth=lag(employment3,1),
     empprevmonthchg=(employment3-empprevmonth))
```

In the larger data frame away from here, the complication is that we have monthly data from 2012-12-01 to 2021-07-01. In the larger data set, there is an NA for empprevmonth in 2012-12-01. That makes sense. Now because there is an NA in the first row, there is an NA in the second (2013-01-01). It is the second row that I need to force the data into the empprevmonth and empprevmonthchg columns.

Comment: @akrun, edited end of question.

Comment: As i mentioned in the comment, can you change those `lag(employment3, 1, default = yourvalue)` so that you can differentiate the `NA` from this value

Comment: @akrun, that works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could change the `default` value in `lag` i.e. `NA` to a different one so as to differentiate

```
library(dplyr)
example <- example%>%
  group_by(indcode3)%>%
  mutate(empprevmonth = lag(employment3,1, default = -999),
        empprevmonthchg=(employment3-empprevmonth))
```